# SEJDA API: How can perform a simple pdf split by all pages?

Tags: sejda

I am trying to split a pdf by all pages grammatically, like this:

```
SimpleSplitParameters params = new SimpleSplitParameters(PredefinedSetOfPages.ALL_PAGES);

PdfFileSource pdfS = PdfFileSource.newInstanceNoPassword(inputFile);
params.setSource(pdfS);
params.setOutput(new DirectoryTaskOutput(outputDirectory));

TaskExecutionService tes = new DefaultTaskExecutionService();
tes.execute(params);
```

... but the is no pdf generated on outputDirectory.

Thank you

Comment: The code you posted seems correct. Sejda usually has some logging output, could you post that as well?